# cs50 recover, recovered images do not match

Tags: c, jpeg, cs50, recover

In the pset4 recover, I've successfully recovered 49 instead of 50 JPGs, and though they look ok, check50 tells me the images don't match:
:) recover.c exists.
:) recover.c compiles.
:) handles lack of forensic image
:( recovers 000.jpg correctly
recovered image does not match
:( recovers middle images correctly
recovered image does not match
:( recovers 049.jpg correctly
049.jpg not found

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

// Declare a function
int find_start(FILE *ptr);
int find_jpeg(FILE *ptr);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Accept only one command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the forensic image\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char *name = argv[1];
    FILE *pointer = fopen(name, "r");
    // Inform the reader if the file can't be opened
    if (pointer == NULL)
    {
        printf("File cannot be opened\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int q = 0;
    // Find the signature for the beginning of the first jpeg
    int d1 = find_start(pointer);
    // Loop
    while (q < 50)
    {
        if (q == 0)
        {
            fseek(pointer, 508, SEEK_CUR);
        }
        int e = find_jpeg(pointer);
        fseek(pointer, -(e + 512), SEEK_CUR);
        BYTE array[e + 512];
        fread(array, 1, e + 512, pointer);
        // Transfer the jpeg from the array to a new file
        char new_name[8];
        int o = sprintf(new_name, "%i%i%i.jpg", q / 100, q / 10 - (q / 100) * 100, q - (q / 100) * 100 - (q / 10) * 10);
        FILE *out = fopen(new_name, "w");
        fwrite(array, 1, e + 512, out);
        q++;
        fclose(out);
    }
    // Close all files
    fclose(pointer);
    return 0;
}

// Define the function for finding the beginning of the first jpeg
int find_start(FILE *ptr)
{
    BYTE i, j, k, l;
    int x;
    int *count = &x;
    *count = 0;
    do
    {
        do
        {
            do
            {
                do
                {
                    i = fgetc(ptr);
                    *count = *count + 1;
                }
                while (i != 0xff);
                j = fgetc(ptr);
            }
            while (j != 0xd8);
            k = fgetc(ptr);
            *count = *count + 1;
        }
        while (k != 0xff);
        l = fgetc(ptr);
        *count = *count + 1;
    }
    while (l < 224 || l > 240);
    return x;
}

int find_jpeg(FILE *ptr)
{
    BYTE i, j, k, l;
    int x;
    int *count = &x;
    *count = 0;
    do
    {
        i = fgetc(ptr);
        j = fgetc(ptr);
        k = fgetc(ptr);
        l = fgetc(ptr);
        fseek(ptr, 508, SEEK_CUR);
        *count = *count + 1;
    }
    while (i != 0xff ||  j != 0xd8 || k != 0xff || l < 224 || l > 240);
    int a = x * 512;
    return a;
}
```

I know it's very long and not elegant, but what is the problem otherwise?

Comment: Are you running the program on a DOS/windows computer?

Comment: You have plenty of [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). and one-letter variables. Those are generally bad and should be avoided. Also please try to avoid defining variables which aren't used, they clutter up the code and make it harder to understand your code. The shown code also lacks plenty of error checking (both `fseek` and `fread` can fail for example). Also are you sure that the format-string `"%i%i%i.jpg"` will never generate a string longer than ***seven*** characters?

Comment: My computer is windows, and I'm running the program in CS50, in chrome if that matters.

Comment: `FILE *pointer = fopen(name, "rb");` Similar for the other file. (this is a result of Bill Gates's Stable Genious)

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("Enter the name of the forensic image\n");
        return 1;`   1) error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout`.  2) when the error is from a C library function, should also output (to `stderr`) the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.  The function: `perror( "fopen failed" );` is made for that job.  Finally, `return 1;` only works from `main()` suggest: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );` where `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are exposed via `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: regarding: `find_jpeg(FILE *ptr)`  there is no 'trash' on the beginning of the input file,  All the bytes of the file are part of the embedded .JPG images.  The very first 4 bytes is the `jpg` identifier. so, read the first 512 bytes into a local buffer, then check the first 4 bytes of the buffer for the 'jpg' identifier.  Strongly suggest to treat everything as `unsigned char`,  not `uint8_t` (nor BYTE)

Comment: OT: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.   ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: regarding function: `find_start()`  this function is quite capable of skipping over a complete image (and does so)  Suggest: when each record is read (always 512 bytes) immediately check the first 4 characters for the 'jpg' identifier (which is a single `if()` statement)

Comment: regarding: `// Inform the reader if the file can't be opened`  also need to inform the user WHY the file cannot be opened.  so replace: ``printf("File cannot be opened\n");` with: `perror( "fopen to read input file failed" );` as that will output to `stderr` both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred.

Comment: regarding; `if (q == 0)
        {
            fseek(pointer, 508, SEEK_CUR);
        }`  A call to `fseek()` is not necessary for this assignment.  Also, as with most C library functions, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful. I.E.  if(  fseek(pointer, 508, SEEK_CUR) == -1 ) { perror( "fseek failed" ); }`

Comment: regarding; `int o = sprintf(new_name, "%i%i%i.jpg", q / 100, q / 10 - (q / 100) * 100, q - (q / 100) * 100 - (q / 10) * 10);`  much better to write: `sprintf( new_name, "%3d.jpg", q);

Comment: regarding: `int e = find_jpeg(pointer);
        fseek(pointer, -(e + 512), SEEK_CUR);
        BYTE array[e + 512];`   This will result in the value `e` getting larger and larger and larger.  Not a good idea.  Suggest: `read()` 512 bytes, then check if first 4 are the 'jpg' identifier.  if identifier found then (if prior output file open, then close it) open new file else if not 'jpg' identifer, then write current 512 byte buffer to the current open output file.

Comment: This CS50 assignment has lots of questions/answers on `stackoverflow.com` Therefore suggest doing a search for: `stackoverflow: CS50+recover` or similar

Comment: you might also want to read:  `https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recover`